# Number rows of query result with index number

Tags: mysql

After some help I have my top ten results from my database. But there is no number that specifies the order. The user currently has to look at the data to understand if the data is ascending or descending order. I would like each piece of data to have a number to specify the ranking.

I am not sure how to go about this, so advice rather than code would be sufficient. A little confused and would rather consult someone who knows what they are doing before I start breaking my code.

Sorry i forgot to add my code:

```
          $result = mysql_query("SELECT coffeeshops.*, services.*, sum(temp.total) as final_total FROM coffeeshops inner join services on coffeeshops.shop_id=services.shop_id
```

inner join (
select 
SUM(comfort + service + ambience + friendliness + spacious + experience + bud_quality + bud_price + drink_price + space_cake + accessibility + toilet_access)/(12) /COUNT(shop_id) AS total, shop_id FROM ratings GROUP BY shop_id
) as temp on coffeeshops.shop_id=temp.shop_id
GROUP BY shop_name
ORDER BY final_total DESC, shop_name ASC limit 10");

```
       while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
        OUTPUT HTML here
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This works to create an incrementing column `rank`, if I understand your question:

```
SELECT 
  @rownum:=@rownum+1 `rank`, 
  column1 
FROM table, (SELECT @rownum:=0) r 
ORDER BY column1 DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

In order to use this with a `GROUP BY` and aggregates, you will probably need to wrap it in a subquery and place the `@rownum` incrementer in the outer query.

Example:

```
SELECT 
  @rownum:=@rownum+1 `rank`, 
  column1,
  column1_count 
FROM (
  SELECT 
   column1,
   COUNT(column1) column1_count
  FROM table
  GROUP BY column1
  ORDER BY COUNT(column1) DESC
) c,
(SELECT @rownum:=0) r
LIMIT 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

Michael's solution will work, but you can also use PHP. If you have an array of your results `$results`, you can sort it, and use a for loop to print out the result number. For example:

```
sort($results); //Asc order, or use rsort($results) for Desc order
for($i=0; $i<count($results); $i++) {
    echo $results[$i].' Rank #: '.($i + 1);
}
```

Comment: fixed it using this but by making +1 to ++. Also moving the echo line outside the foreach. thanks

Comment: infact just using:    

                  $i = 1;    
                  echo $result[$i].' Rank #: '.($i ++);  // Outputs Top ten ranking